# Como salvar as alterações de cor em uma linha Datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Preciso salvar as alterações de cor que o usuário faz no datagrid.

Atualmente as cores são trocadas de acordo com a seleção do usuário utilizando o seguinte código:

```
dgv1.CurrentRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red; //Troca a cor da linha para vermelho
```

porém se acontece algum reset do form , o datagrid retorna para a cor padrão (branco).

Há alguma forma de salvar essas mudanças e carrega-las no momento do load do datagrid?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o [System.IO.File](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=net-5.0) para ler e salvar um arquivo contendo a cor.
Salvando a cor:

```
var cor = dgv1.CurrentRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor;
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("cor.txt", $"{cor.R.ToString()},{cor.G.ToString()},{cor.B.ToString()}");
```

Carregando a cor:

```
string[] rgb = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("cor.txt").Split(",");
int r = int.Parse(rgb[0]);
int g = int.Parse(rgb[1]);
int b = int.Parse(rgb[2]);
dgv1.CurrentRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(r, g, b);
```